# What is the idiomatic way to bind my select's codomain to a webservice's result set which comes from another select's selected value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

Suppose I have a RESTful webservice `TestRestService` which has two methods: `getData` and `getOtherData(id)`.

In my angularjs controller I initialize a `select` with the data returned by `getData`:

```
TestRestService.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
});

<select class="form-control" 
        data-ng-options="data.id for data in myData"
        data-ng-model="selectedData"></select>
```

Now what is the idiomatic way for filling up my other select:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-ng-options="data.id for data in otherData"
    data-ng-model="selectedOtherData"></select>
```

which can be filled by calling `TestRestService.getOtherData(id)`?

I know that I can set up an event listener for selection change but I've heard that angularjs' two-way data binding can be used to simplify this problem. I just don't know how (yet).

Comment: I am confused as to what the issue is.  If are able to load data from one service method and use it to populate a select; why can't you use the same approach to populate a different select from a different service?

Comment: Because `getOtherData()` should be called with `selectedData`'s `id`.

Comment: The just pass selectedData's ID as a parameter into the getOtherData() service method.  How you do this depends on how the service is setup to handle it.  ( Form post? Get call? Something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-ng-options="data.id for data in myData"
    data-ng-model="selectedData"
    data-ng-change="GetMoreData(data.id)"
></select>
```

in Controller:

```
$scope.GetMoreData =function(uniqueID){
TestRestService.getOtherData().then(function(data) {
$scope.myOtherData = data;
});
```

Hope i made myself clear.

Comment: This is what I already know as I've said it in my answer but thanks.

Comment: well if you simply want to not go throw the controller create your own directive and put the service as resource. but that seems to me complex again.